# reload button in .js file for simple slideshow, can't make it work

Tags: javascript, reload

Solved

Hello guys I'm just starting out with the basic javascript and was just wondering how I can call this function from the button while keeping all the code inside gallery.js

```
<input type="button" value="Reload Page" onClick="window.location.reload()">
```

gallery.js file

```
var slideShow = new Array();
slideShow[0]="images/1.jpg";
slideShow[1]="images/2.jpg";
slideShow[2]="images/3.jpg";
slideShow[3]="images/4.jpg";
slideShow[4]="images/5.jpg";//loads pictures
slideShow[5]="images/6.jpg";
var thisPic = 0;

function reloadURL()
{
    window.location.reload();
}   

function processNext() {
    if (document.images && thisPic < 5) { //process checks if this pic is less than 2
        thisPic++;
        document.getElementById("picture").src=slideShow[thisPic];
    else if( window.location.reload()
    }
}
window.onload = init; //initially loads

function init() {
document.getElementById("next").onclick=processNext; //on button click next picture     is shown


}
```

gallery.html

```
<div id="content">
<h2>Gallery</h2>
    <p>This is the gallery</p>
    <img src="images/1.jpg" id="picture" alt="displays a slide show of 5 pictures"/><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Press this button for next picture" id="next" />
    <input type="button" value="Reload" onclick="reloadURL();" />

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:
`<input type="button" value="Reload Page" onClick="processNext();">`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should include the JavaScript file in the `<head>` section of your html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="gallery.js"></script>
```

Then you can call any function included in that file:

```
<input type="button" value="Reload Page" onClick="processNext();">
```

Comment: Still not really working for me. I've already got the     <script type="text/javascript" src="gallery.js"></script> in the head

Comment: Press F12 in Firefox or Chrome, Select "Net" or "Network" and look in the right bottom corner if it shows any errors..?